# 2 INPUT em 1 campo só

Tags: html, formulário, input

Tenho um formulário que é fornecido pelo banco para gerar um boleto bancário.

Eu preciso dividir o campo "nome" em dois no meu formulário html.

Preciso pegar o NOME do cliente e também o NUMERO do processo dele.

Exemplo:
Campo 1: "Nome do Aluno Fulano de Tal"
Campo 2: "Processo numero 999999999"

O resultado deve ser enviado junto ao banco pelo seguinte input:

```
<input size="25" maxlength="50" name="nomeSacado" type="text" />
```

O resultado deve ser enviado assim: "Nome do Aluno Fulano de Tal Processo numero 999999999". Tudo no mesmo input "nomeSacado".

Isso deve ser mamão com açúcar, mas não pra mim. rsrs

Alguém pode ajudar?

Desde já obrigado.
Rafael

Comment: Qual framework front você está usando? Jquery, Angular?

Comment: Não para entender o que você quer. Pode fazer um exemplo mais concreto e detalhado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript Puro.

```js
function Concatena()
{
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var numProcesso = document.getElementById('numProcesso').value; 
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacado').value=nome+ " " + numProcesso;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='nome' value='Nome do Aluno Fulano de Tal' size="28"/>
<input type='text' id='numProcesso' value='Processo numero 999999999' size="27"/>
<input type='text' id='nomeSacado' name='nomeSacado' size="58" onclick='Concatena();' placeholder="Clique aqui para concatenar"/>
```

**Como fazemos pra esse campo rodar hidden sem o usuário precisar clicar em nada pra concatenar?**

- Para rodar hidden basta alterar o type text `<input type='text' ...` para hidden  `<input type='hidden' ....`
- Sem precisar clicar em nada para concatenar podemos criar uma função com execução imediata (IIFE) `(function(){})();`

<sub>O IIFE significa "Immediately-invoked function expression", ou então podemos chamar de função imediata. Como o próprio nome diz, é uma função em Javascript executada logo que definida.</sub>

> Não vou no exemplo a seguir setar o input como hidden e nem retirar o `size="58"` para que se possa observar o resultado da execução do código.

```js
(function() { 
   //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var numProcesso = document.getElementById('numProcesso').value; 
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacado').value=nome+ " " + numProcesso;
  
}());
```

```html
<input type='text' id='nome' value='Nome do Aluno Fulano de Tal' size="28"/>
<input type='text' id='numProcesso' value='Processo numero 999999999' size="27"/>
<input type='text' id='nomeSacado' name='nomeSacado' size="58">
```

**Se houver necessidade de correção nos campos, então faça assim:**

Utilize o evento `onKeyup` que é disparado quando a tecla é largada.

```js
function Concatena() { 
   //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var numProcesso = document.getElementById('numProcesso').value; 
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacado').value=nome+ " " + numProcesso;
  
}Concatena();
```

```html
<input type='text' id='nome' value='Nome do Aluno Fulano de Tal' size="28" onKeyup='Concatena();'>
<input type='text' id='numProcesso' value='Processo numero 999999999' size="27" onKeyup='Concatena();'>
<input type='text' id='nomeSacado' name='nomeSacado' size="58">
```

> O javascript deve estar após o HTML

Comment: Amigo, consegui. Porém o concatena só funciona quando clico no campo text nomeSacado.

Comment: Como fazemos pra esse campo rodar hidden sem o usuario precisar clicar em nada pra concatenar? Obrigado pelo seu help!

Comment: Leo, agora deu certo!!! Cara, MUITO OBRIGADO!!! Você e toda galera daqui são demais!!! abração!

Answer (score 1):

Dá para fazer com javascript ou concatenar os dois campos no seu backend no caso estou fazendo com javascript usando jquery e um input hidden que vai receber o valor concatenado:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="[your_action]" method="post" id="form">
    <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome">
    <input name="processo" type="text" id="processo">
    <input name="nomeSacado" type="hidden" id="nomeSacado">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var nome = $('#nome').val();
        var processo = $('#nome').val();
        $('#nomeSacado').val(nome + ' ' + processo);
    })
</script>
```